# login through Auth In Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

In login process in zend, We store the user information in Zend_Auth, but it creates a problem, the problem is that if user does not make any activity till 15 minutes or more on that site then the user automatically becomes logout.
Please tell me, for which reason it occur.

```
$frontendOptions = array(
                'automatic_serialization' => true,
                'lifetime'                => NULL
            );
            $backendOptions  = array(
            //    'cacheDir' => TMP_DIR . DS . 'cache' . DS . 'meta'
            );

            $cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'File', $frontendOptions, $backendOptions);
            Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultMetadataCache($cache);
```

Is this code is responsible for such condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happens due to conflict as i have already face this problem.
if you are working on two projects and both are at same address means you are working on two projects and place both on same server then they create conflict.

To test it open both projects on same browser and login and make logout on any one and you will see that other has been also logout.

place them on different server this will not happens.

Comment: yes, the problem has resolved when i place my project on another server. Thanks sir.

Answer (score 4):

Because this is the normal behavior of Zend. Every **[session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)** has a time limit and sessions have a default timeout. You can just tell to the session to wait more time using something like this:

```
Zend_Session::rememberMe($sessionLifetime)
```

Comment: sir, I have used it but it is not helpful me. after using it session destroy immediately. Please provide any other solution

Comment: You have not to use session_destroy. Anyway if you want more help, you can create a new question, posting part of your code and you'll get the help you need.

Comment: I have edited my code can you explain it and tell is this code responsible for such condition.

Comment: @GauravVashishtha since this is a very different question, you should open another thread.